# How to make repository and sql command work together in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

In my Orchard project, I used both SQL command (to get data) and repository method (to update data).

But they don't work together:

Step 1: I uses SQL command to get data.

Step 2: uses repository() to update these data.

Step 3: uses SQL command to get updated data.

When step 3 was called, the database become hanging.

It's may be because repository() is still holding database after updated data, therefore SQL command must wait until repository releases the database.

So, how to force repository releases updated database right after it finished its work ?

Comment: Are you getting the nHibernate session in order to perform all these operations? What kind of data is this? Any particular reason not to go through the content manager?

Comment: Because these datas are just normal Record, they are not used as a Part, so I update them by using Repository, I uses these kind of data as relationship between many ContentType, or children datas.

Comment: You can release database by call (repository.Flush()) after update, but you should not have any need to do this at all.

Comment: You didn't answer my other questions. You might also want to consider the many other ways to establish relationships between content items in Orchard, out of which the manual option is probably the worst. I wrote a series of blog posts that you'll be able to find with https://www.google.com/?q=site%3Aweblogs.asp.net%2Fbleroy%20orchard%20relationships

Comment: Ah, um, sorry, about nHibernate session, I don't know anything about it, I'm learning Orchard, I uses only basic methods like ContentManager.Get() , Repository Fetch, Update, I don't know about nHibernate session. So, if I understands what nHibernate session is, I can resolve this problem ?

And thanks about your blog, I will learn from it.